# How to navigate to top/bottom of page in mobile firefox

Tags: firefox-for-android, user-interface

Is there a way to quickly navigate to the top/bottom of the current page in mobile firefox (i.e. the equivalent of using the home/end keys in the desktop version)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add an add-on to help accomplish what you asked. [Top and Bottom scroll buttons](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/top-and-bottom-scroll-buttons/) adds buttons to scroll to the top or bottom of a page.

> This extension adds two beautiful buttons at the corner of each page for fast scrolling to the top or the bottom of the page.
>
> The buttons are customisable. You can change its size, transparency, position and the way they are scrolling.
>   You can also set the buttons to auto hide so you'll see them only when you want.

[image: IMG:]

**Disclaimer:** I am just a user of the addon, not related to its developer.

Comment: Thanks! I was hoping to accomplish it without an extension and thought that I must just be overlooking the thing in the UI. Apparently I wasn't...

Comment: This extension is not compatible with the mobile version any more.

Answer (score 2):

You can get these two extensions:

[Go to Top of Page Button](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/go-to-top-of-page-button/)

[Got to Bottom of Page Button](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/go-to-top-of-page-button/)

They will put a button in the toolbar labeled `Top` and `Bottom`

Comment: Your answer also works of course, I decided to accept the other because it gives me both buttons in one. Might still be useful for people that for some reason only want one and not the other :)